# Python, Grouping a list by specific order

Tags: python, loops

I want to group items in a list with a specific order. The order I want is in `groups` and the `items` must be grouped by that order.
The solution I've tried is to pop the item[index] in items when I append it to temp, but it's not a good idea to manipulate a list while iterating it.

Is there a better approach or any other way to optimize this sample code?

```py
groups = ["d", "c", "a", "b"]
items = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "a"]
result = []
for group in groups:
    temp = []
    for item in items:
        if item == group:
            temp.append(item)
    result.extend(temp)
    
print(result)
```

Comment: What is the *specfic* order?  The logic is unclear here.  What you expect from the input example?

Comment: @DanielHao. As with many beginners, OP's prose is not crystal clear. However, the code sample seems pretty unambiguous, unless I'm really missing something. That's why a MCVE is so important, especially when you're first learning.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're sorting more than grouping. There are a couple of ways to approach this.

One way would be a sort with a key based on `groups`. To avoid the `O(n)` lookup every time you call `groups.index`, convert it to `dict` and use `get` or `__getitem__` instead:

```
groupdict = {g: i for i, g in enumerate(groups)}
result = sorted(items, key=groupdict.__getitem__)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the frequency of all the items, then flatten in order of groups... eg:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(items)
result = [k for k in groups for n in range(counts[k])]
# ['d', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

Comment: You did my second answer before I could type it up :) The only advantage of sorting is if you want to keep your mutable objects distinct

Comment: @MadPhysicist ironically - I was just about to put an edit in that's pretty much your answer :p

Comment: @DanielHao practice, practice and practice :)

Comment: I knew you'd say that :p

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to sort the list; you can just count how many instances of an item there are, then add that many instances to your result list. Iterate through your `groups` list. You begin with `"d"`. There is one instance of `"d"` in `items`. Therefore, you append `"d"` to `result` one time.

```
groups = ["d", "c", "a", "b"]
items = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "a"]
result = []

for group in groups:
    for i in range(items.count(group)):
        result.append(group)

print(result)
# ['d', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

Comment: That's O(g * i). The other two solutions are O(g + i) and O(g + i log i), respectively, which is optimal and nearly optimal. I posted be nearly optimal solution because it has certain other desirable features. Jon posted the optimal solution because it's optimal.

Comment: Also, what you're doing is effectively a sort, just less efficient